# Mongoose $inc does nothing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, increment, mongoose-schema

This is my Mongoose schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// define the schema for our campaign model
var campaignSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    priority: Number,
    start: String,
    end: String,
    platforms:[String],
    contents:[
        {
            id:Number,
            img:String,
            link:String,
            height:Number,
            width:Number,
            views:Number,
            clicks:Number
        }
    ]  
});

// create the model for campaigns and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('Campaign', campaignSchema);
```

When I try increasing any `Number` field, whether in `contents` array or `priority`, it simply does nothing, no error, value just stays the same..

This is how I try to do it:

`Campaign.update({"_id": req.query.campaignID}, {$inc : {priority : 1} });`

But its value stays `0`

To prevent your questions, ofcourse, I tried getting `campaign` with `_id == req.query.campaignID` and it exists

Comment: You need [`.exec()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#update_update) or a callback as last argument or even `then()` for a Promise. Unless one of those is present then nothing even gets sent to the server.

Comment: You're right, I got confused by https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/ as in example there there is no callback or exec.
Thanks a lot, I lose few hours debugging this... please make your comment a answer and I will accept it!